# Diferença de horário TimeSpan em formato 24hrs

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estou fazendo essa pergunta pois não localizei nenhum tópico com o meu problema, que é bem semelhante a outros.

Eu tenho 2 campos `TimeSpan?` sendo que um é referente ao **horário de entrada** e o outro ao **horário de saída**.

Eu quero saber a diferença de hora, então se a pessoa trabalha das 08:00 as 10:00, ele trabalhou 2 horas.

Isso é bem simples, talvez com um Compare ou um sub eu consiga extrair esse valor total, porém quando eu informo que a pessoa entrou as 17:00 e saiu as 16:00 ele me retorna 1, sendo que ele trabalhou 23 horas

Como eu posso fazer esse calculo?

Comment: se ele trabalhou das 16(4 horas) e saiu as 17(5 horas), ele vai retornar uma hora mesmo, se você esta tentando dizer que ele entrou em uma dia e saiu no outro você também tem que comparar o dia.

Comment: Me confundi no texto, se ele entrou as 17 e saiu as 16 horas, já corrigi no texto.

Comment: "quando eu informo que a pessoa entrou as 16:00 e saiu as 17:00 ele me retorna 1, sendo que ele trabalhou 23 horas" pelo que entendi isso está certo, ele deveria retornar 23 se a pessoa entra às 17 e sai às 16, não?

Comment: @rLinhares exatamente, é nisso que eu estou tendo dificuldade, saber das 17 até as 16 hrs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4946393/4551469 vê se essa forma dá certo `var hours = (datevalue1 - datevalue2).TotalHours;`

Comment: Teoricamente os valores nunca vão ser fixos então ela pode informar que seja entrada 15hrs e saida as 18hrs, quanto pode também ser  das 18hrs até as 17hrs do outro dia. Eu teria que fazer uma verificação se a data saida fosse menor que a data de entrada e adicionar 1 dia na data saida, seria isso ?

Comment: Há uma confusão aí. Você precisa como resposta de um período, um intervalo de tempo, então a resposta será um `TimeSpan`. A entrada de dados é a hora de entrada e hora de saída, portanto são dois pontos no tempo, ou seja, devem ser `DateTime`. Quando começa errado fica difícil fazer certo.

Comment: Já resolvi, vocês estavam corretos, tudo que tive que fazer era converter para `DateTime` e adicionar 1 dia para a data de saída quando ela for menor que a data de entrada.

Comment: E utilizei o TotalHours que o @rLinhares informou. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há uma confusão aí.

Você precisa como resposta de **um período**, um intervalo de tempo, então a resposta será um `TimeSpan`.

A entrada de dados é a hora de entrada e hora de saída, portanto são dois **pontos no tempo**, ou seja, devem ser `DateTime`.

Quando começa errado fica difícil fazer certo. Transforme essas horas em `DateTime` e aí basta fazer uma subtração.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var objeto = new AlgumaClasse();
        objeto.HoraEntrada = DateTime.Now;
        objeto.HoraSaida = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).AddMinutes(43).AddSeconds(22);
        WriteLine($"Permaneceu {(objeto.TempoPermanencia().ToString(@"hh\:mm"))}");
    }
}

class AlgumaClasse {
    public DateTime HoraEntrada { get; set; }

    public DateTime HoraSaida { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan TempoPermanencia() => HoraSaida - HoraEntrada;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JOXeCE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BmfGLg). Também [coloquei no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Difference.cs).

Comment: Boa, o texto está correto mas o código não é a solução, falta bastante coisa mas obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Eu respondi em cima do que colocou na pergunta que falta bastante coisa.

Answer (score 0):

O TimeSpan tem a opção de ter os dias também. No construtor dele tem uma sobrecarga que você informa (days, hours, minutes, seconds) e se você informar a quantidade de dias o calculo ficará mais preciso.

Exemplo:

```
    TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(0,17,0,0);
    TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(1,16,0,0); //Repare que aqui tem um dia.

    var result = t2-t1;
    Console.Write(result.ToString()); // Resultado será 23:00:00
```

Se na variável t2 instânciar passando o primeiro parametro como zero, verá que o resultado será -01:00:00. O código acima pode ser verificado aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUO2AI

Assim se você persiste esses campos em algum lugar, no momento de persistir você deveria considerar a quantidade de dias no seu timespan.